# CLI proxy for terminal shell

Tags: python, shell, netmiko

I often deal with cheap networking hardware that has poor CLI interface, i.e. not many commands to display information related to the health of the device or the ongoing processes and flows.
I thought then to write a **Python** script based on **netmiko** that gets my customized input, translates into commands available on the device and send them to it (through whatever protocol CLI or NETCONF for instance), gets back the outputs, extracts the needed pieces of information from each of them and put them together in an **aggregated view**.

I only have knowledge of Python and netmiko but not as to writing a shell.
My question is: from where to start? Is there anything already available without re-inventing the wheel (though I do prefer programming)?

TIA

Comment: Look at [cmd](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/cmd.html) module from Python standard library and similar module from pip: [cmd2](https://cmd2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/first_app.html)

Comment: @StanislavIvanov, it sounds promising, thanks!